# respondsToSelector to an id type object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

In my class there is a method let say `-aMethod:` which takes an `id` type parameters and doing some operation with that object. Now I want to call a method let say `-someMethod` of that object. But the problem is object type is `id` and I can't cast it as I don't know which type of object will be come here. Below my code but it's showing error `no know instant method for the selector someMethod`. Can any body help to handle that type of situation.

I don't want to use block or delegate.

```
- (void)aMethod:(id)anObject
{
    // other stuff
    if([anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]) [anObject someMethod];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply have to show the compiler the method in any way. You need not to type the receiver that way. (But I would do that.) Personally I prefer to have a protocol that collects the methods.

```
@protocol MyDelegateProtocol
- (void)someMethod;
@end

// You do not have to use that protocol for typing.
// So you can use your code as you did.
```

Another way is to add a category to a class.

```
@interface AnyClassIncludingNSObject( MyDelegateAddition )
- (void)someMethod;
@end
```

Do *not* implement that category.

A third solution is to add the method to the class sending the message.

```
- (void)someMethod {}
```

It is always the same: The compiler has to see it one time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your third solution meet my requirement

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the exact class type that you will be sent you should create a protocol and have all classes that might be sent (and which implement the target method) confirm to that protocol. Now you can cast to (or set the parameter passed to) `id < MyProtocol >` and the compiler will be happy.

Comment: I knew that it can be solved by the delegate or block but I don't want to do that.

Comment: You do not need that. The compiler simply wants to see the method anyway.

Comment: @TapasPal: Feel free to ignore good advice, but do it at your own peril.

Comment: @gnasher729 I knew that those all are the good point but I mention in my question that I don't wanna use delegate. Because sometimes doing something different will increase your knowledge.

Comment: A protocol isn't a delegate, and a delegate isn't the only purpose of a protocol. There are other approaches to 'trick' the compiler into allowing the call, but a protocol is the correct approach and the most informative to people reading the code about the intention of the author.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers here:

If for some reason you don't want to declare a protocol, you can do it like this:

```
if ([anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]) {
    [anObject performSelector:@selector(someMethod)];
}
```

There is also `performSelector:withObject:` if you need to pass an argument, `performSelectorOnMainThread` and others.

Comment: But still it's show warning `undeclared selector someMethod`

Comment: @TapasPal, sorry, I thought that the main issue is the `No known instance method` error. Still, I'll leave the answer, since someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you don't want to do this the right way as other people suggested. So, in order to solve this, I would first remove the warning:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"

... your code here ...

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

just move your code in between `#pragma`s.

Second, I would `#import` the class that has the `someMethod` declared, and just cast the the 'unknown' object to that class when calling the method. 
Like: `[(MySuperClassThatHasSomeMethodDeclared *)anObject someMethod];`

And, yeah, don't worry, your `someMethod` will be called on the object you have passed.

So, here is your DIRTY way of solving the problem. Good Luck!

Comment: I had already solved this situation using `protocol` before posting the question. That's why I mention in my question without using `block or delegate`. I just wanted to know the other way if any. Is it a bad practice to know the other solution.????

Comment: Then, you had to mention that in your question. In your question, you seem like to be the poorest person that couldn't solve the issue, but you kept the ignoring the right answers, that's why I answered this way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of `NSObject` which is a type of your requirement. In your case `AnObject`.

Now implement `someMethod` in this class and then use this class as an parameter instead of `id`.

So that you can able to call and implement `someMethod` as you expect.